# Using yarn in travis enterprise

Tags: travis-ci, yarnpkg

Travis [supports yarn](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2016-11-21-travis-ci-now-supports-yarn) but it doesn't seem to work in their enterprise solution that seems to be an older version.

The question is: how can I [install yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install) on Travis enterprise **without sudo**?

I assume even if I install Yarn using

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

Travis will not automatically use `yarn` instead of `npm` as mentioned in their blog. Or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instructions given in https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-tab

Or, look at how we do it: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/02fb3b35c35cb7d69dd28923404c4cc02dc57ddd/lib/travis/build/script/node_js.rb#L211-L219

Also, if you have support questions regarding Travis Enterprise, you could email us at enterprise@travis-ci.com.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried that. Yarn is installed and added to path but still NPM is being used. Contacted support for more help.